# How to debug Trac?

Tags: trac

I have installed Trac and it reports the following error when I'm trying to access its page:

```
Internal Server Error

TracError: IOError: (13, 'Permission denied')
```

Any suggestions what needs to be checked?

Comment: Since you are getting a permission denied error the probably is almost certainly related to file-system permissions somewhere.  I don't know Trac, but I would guess it needs to have a temp directory or data directory somewhere to be writeable.

Comment: I have chowned its trac's directory to apache.

Comment: enable logging (to file, debug level); that should give a traceback that will have useful clues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enable debug in trac.ini. Restart apache (usually is ran behind apache) and check for errors in trac.log
Also verify error.log from apache.

I guess you have to change the owner to apache's user for all files and dirs of your trac instance.

Comment: The trac.log is empty. It does not write anything there.

Comment: Changing the owner to apache's user fixed it. Thanks