# My apache is giving file not found error

Tags: apache-2.2, trac

I am installing trac. But My apache is not working properly. It shows me the file not found error. Why this error comes. I follows the link `http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/MySqlDb`

Help me out.

Apache is not showing any error. Error log is empty. Even http://localhost gives error.

```
Internal Server Error

TracError: IOError: (2, 'No such file or directory')
```

Comment: For a decent response you need to be way more verbose than that when asking questions. Please specify the operating system you use, paste the meaningful lines from Apache error log, show us the Apache config and so on.

Comment: Internal Server Error

TracError: IOError: (2, 'No such file or directory')

Comment: Ubuntu is My OS.

Comment: please use the edit button (just under the question) to add details. We really need more than what you've posted so far...

Answer (score 0):

There is a [similar question here](https://serverfault.com/questions/151858/how-to-debug-trac) that you could follow to identify the problem (like logging from php.ini).